# Headings sizes h1 h2 h3 in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a problem with headings in Firefox.

Website is at http://toto-bongo.heroku.com/blog

**Firefox Screenshot**
[image]

**Chrome Screenshot**
[image]

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: http://toto-bongo.heroku.com/blog

Comment: I was losing my mind trying to get styles to be consistent until I started using Reset and Rebuild stylesheets. I suggest you start there.

Comment: On that blog post, I don't see the "this is an h1" text anywhere.  So either you changed the HTML or ... something.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem will be fixed if you simply define the sizes of the elements in your CSS. If you're worried about the size of all of your elements, your best bet is to use a reset stylesheet, which will really help you if you're worried about cross-browser compatibility. Using a reset stylesheet forces you to define specific atributes to each tag that you use, thus eliminating any ambiguity between browsers.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the most likely cause of this is mismatched open and close tags, which the browsers interpret differently. Unless, of course, you are specifying styles for these tags.

Since there's no link we can look at, it seems unlikely you'll get a definitive answer here. But I would be surprised if FireFox really shows `<H1>` tags that small out of the box.

Comment: Exactly, @daniel please upload this page somewhere and post the link.

Comment: Or at least post some HTML. (And it might help if you started accepting a few more answers as well!)

Comment: New screen shots taken from:
toto-bongo.heroku.com/blog

Comment: @daniel: I didn't see anything immediately that would cause this. But you have a few quirks in your HTML. For example, I don't see the `</html>` tag. Beyond that, you are using stylesheets. It would take you a second to remove the stylesheet and see if the issue remains.

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by [custom styles](http://www.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html#usercss) in your `userContent.css` file.  This file is in your [Firefox profile folder](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles), in the `chrome` directory.

Comment: I searched for this file everywere in the system and I could'nt find, there is a UserContent-example.css which is just comments

Comment: This isn't the culprit, then.  It would be in the same folder as `userContent-example.css`.  :-/