# Firefox 4 <sections> and headers

Tags: html, css, firefox, firefox4

From this question I started looking:
 [Firefox screwing up headings sizes h1 h2 h3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954396/firefox-screwing-up-headings-sizes-h1-h2-h3)

Here is a html snippet that will show the issue:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
    <section>
      <h1>This is an h1</h1>
      <h2>This is an h2</h2>
      <h3>This is an h3</h3>
      <h4>This is an h4</h4>
    </section>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

so save that into test.html and open it in firefox 4 and in chrome, the h1 tag shows way smaller in firefox 4.

Can anyone explain me how to fix this ?

Comment: Very smaller in comparison or just different between browsers?

Comment: Both, very small in comparisson and quite different from Chrome

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use `<h1>` tag multiple times in the same document as part of HTML5.  The `<h1>` tag is specifically used as a title for a section.  Apparently, FireFox implements the nested section as an indication to reduce the size of the `<h1>` for the sub-section, which makes sense, while Chrome does not.

More Info

- http://brugbart.com/References/html-section-tag
- http://brokensyllabus.blogspot.com/2008/02/proper-use-of-h1-tag.html

Comment: +1 As a nice explanation. But I think that you also needs to answer it: "Can anyone explain me how to fix this?".

Comment: Ok but then you can't mix h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 and <sections>

Comment: BTW, there is just no way to use <sections> correctly accross browsers. In firefox you have to use h1 only, but if you do so, it won't show correctly in IE\chrome\safari and if you use h2-h6 then it won't show correctly if firefox.

Comment: The point of `<section>` is that inside a section all headings mean "one thing smaller".  So `<h1>` inside a `<section>` is the same thing as `<h2>` and if your `<section>`s were nested two deep it would be the same as `<h3>`.

Comment: Well that would be nice if it happened accross browser this only happens inside firefox. h1 inside a section == h2 only in firefox, its bigger in chrome and IE.

Answer (score 1):

What about using CSS to specify the size of all h1 tags?  Then, it shouldn't matter whether it is within a section or anything else.

Comment: Well yes you can but that's not the point of using sections and headings